# How to generate white noise in matlab? N0 = 50dB/Hz

Tags: matlab, signals, communication, noise

I want to generate white noise in matlab.

```
clc;
clear;
mu=0;
sigma=1;
noise= sigma *randn(1,10)+mu
```

I can generate with this code but I guess I am not using noise power value. Can someone help me?

Comment: You should initially compute noise power as `N0*W` where `W` is bandwidth. Then use `sigma` equal to the square root of that power

Comment: Thank very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are dedicated functions from MATLAB to add white Gaussian noise: [`wgn()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/wgn.html) and [`awgn()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/awgn.html).

```
sig = ones(100,1)
% add white Gaussian noise
snr = 50; % signal-to-noise ratio
sig_wgn = awgn(sig,snr,'measured')
```

if you want to do it yourself, note that `rand()` only returns numbers in [0,1], so you will need to scale + shift it to `2*(rand(,10)-0.5)` to get a symmetric output that you than can scale to your range

Comment: 'wgn' requires Communications Toolbox.

Comment: 'awgn' requires Communications Toolbox.